# Почему появляются странные черные полосы и тени на модели в WPF проекте

Tags: c#, wpf, графика

Я пытался загрузить 3D модель в свой WPF проект, скопировав вершины и треугольники из obj файла. Появились странные черные треугольники независимо от того, где находится свет. Я пробовал добавлять нормали, указанные в obj файле, пробовал вычислять нормаль для каждой точки. Тени просто меняют свое положение, но не исчезают.

```
public void Draw(Viewport3D Viewport)
{
    MeshGeometry3D StandMesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

    for (int i = 0; i < verticies.Length - 2; i += 3)
        StandMesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(verticies[i], verticies[i + 1], verticies[i + 2]));

    foreach (var index in indices)
        StandMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(index);

    GeometryModel3D StandGeometry = new GeometryModel3D(StandMesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.DarkGray));

    ModelVisual3D StandModel = new ModelVisual3D();

    StandModel.Content = StandGeometry;

    Viewport.Children.Add(StandModel);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это просто из-за недостаточной детализации может быть, потому изображение не ровно круглое, а большими треугольниками, хоть сглаживание их немного и скрашивает